# Controlling CPU frequency

Tags: cpu, turbo-boost

I have a Dell Latitude e6410 what has i5-520M processor.

It's running between 1.2-2.4 GHz. I think my turbo is switched off. How could I turn on to achive ~3 GHz? In my previous laptop I simply used that command to turn on the turbo, but now I don't have that directory.

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

[Some info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-OzTlSlzeopakVieUE3bXdpV2M/view?usp=sharing) about my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that no turbo is disabled (as you have already done), and the CPU is allowed to run at 100%:

```
echo 0 | sydo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
```

The highest turbo frequency kicks in only if the thermal conditions are correct. Depending on the CPU model, different turbo levels are possible depending on the type of load and number of CPUs loaded.  You may find just 1 CPU can run at 100% turbo, where as with two or more CPUs there maximum turbo speed is less than 100%; it really depends on many of the variable characteristics of the processor design and kind of load.